# Using Q service to chain asynchronous events

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I understand the basics of the Q service but am having trouble implementing it. I have a series of events, the second which depends on the first returning.

Promise setup

```
var Q  = require('q');

var dataPromise = getCustomerId();

dataPromise  
.then(function(data) {
    console.log('Success!', data);
    getGUID(req, res, next);
}, function(error) {
    console.log('Failure...', error);
});  

};
```

getCustomerId()

```
var getCustomerId = function() {

var getCustomerIdOptions = {
  options...
};

var deferred = Q.defer();
request(getCustomerIdOptions, function(err,resp,body){
  if(err){
    deferred.reject(err);
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }else{
    deferred.resolve(body);
  }
  return deferred.promise;
});
};
```

I think I'm returning the deferred promise correctly, but am returning an error that dataPromise does not have a "then" property, it is undefined.

Comment: Fix your indentation and you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning the promise in the `request()` callback.

The actual `getCustomerId()` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks! thats makes sense.